# Two tkinter Objects act differently when bound on the same event

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am creating instances of two different objects (features_object and line_object) on a canvas. The idea is to connect several of the features by lines (). Later on when features are moved around the lines should follow.

At the moment my issue is that, when I apply the delete method on the lines I can delete them (Lines created between features by left mouse click. Line deleted by right mouse double click). However with the similar method of the feature class nothing happens! I cannot delete the features! The features seem invisible on the canvas! Is there any solution to that?

Thanks a lot!

```
from tkinter import Tk, Frame, Canvas, Text, END, TRUE, BOTH, CURRENT

click = 0


class line_object:
    all_connections = []
    def __init__(self):
        self.connections_data = []

    def create_line(self, master, start_elem, end_elem, tag_start, tag_end):
        self.master = master
        self.start_elem = start_elem
        self.end_elem = end_elem
        self.tag_start = tag_start
        self.tag_end = tag_end

        self.start_x = self.master.coords(self.start_elem)[0]
        self.start_y = self.master.coords(self.start_elem)[1]
        self.end_x = self.master.coords(self.end_elem)[0]
        self.end_y = self.master.coords(self.end_elem)[1]

        self.line_tag = (f'Connector_{self.start_elem}_{self.end_elem}', 'connection', 'drag')
        self.master.delete(self.line_tag)

        self.line_id = self.master.create_line(self.start_x, self.start_y, self.end_x, self.end_y, fill="red", width=6, tags=(self.line_tag, self.tag_start, self.tag_end))
        self.master.tag_lower(self.line_id)

        self.bind_events_lines()

    def bind_events_lines(self):
        self.master.bind('<Double Button-3>', self.deleteLine)

    def deleteLine(self, event=None):
        actual = self.master.find_withtag(CURRENT)
        self.master.delete(actual)
 

class features_object():
    
    def __init__(self):

        self.features_data = []

    def create_feature(self, master, feature_text, feature_xpos, feature_ypos, feature_color):
        self.master = master
        self.feature_text = feature_text
        self.feature_xpos = feature_xpos
        self.feature_ypos = feature_ypos
        self.feature_color = feature_color

        self.feature_frame = Frame(self.master, bg=self.feature_color, border=20)   
        self.feature_text = Text(self.feature_frame, font=("Helvetica", 12), relief='flat', width=20, height=3, selectbackground=self.feature_color, selectforeground="black", exportselection=TRUE)
        self.feature_text.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky='w')
        self.feature_text.config(wrap='word')
        self.feature_text.insert(END, feature_text)
        self.feature_tags = 'drag'
        self.feature_id = self.master.create_window(self.feature_xpos, self.feature_ypos, window=self.feature_frame, tags=self.feature_tags)
        self.master.itemconfigure(self.feature_id, tags=[self.feature_id])
        self.bind_events_features()

    def bind_events_features(self):
        self.feature_frame.bind('<Button-1>', self.draw_line_with_bind)
        self.feature_frame.bind('<Double Button-3>', self.deleteFeature)

    def deleteFeature(self, event):
        actual = self.master.find_withtag(CURRENT)
        self.master.delete(actual)

    def draw_line_with_bind(self, event):
        global click, start_x, start_y, end_x, end_y, elem_start, tag_start
        
        if click == 0:
            elem_start = self.feature_id
            tag_start = f'{elem_start}'
            click = 1 
        elif click == 1:
            elem_end = self.feature_id
            tag_end = f'{elem_end}'
            lin = line_object()
            self.connection = lin.create_line(draw_canvas, elem_start, elem_end, tag_start, tag_end)
            click = 0 

window = Tk()
window.geometry("1000x800")

frame_start = Frame(window)
frame_start.pack(expand=TRUE, fill=BOTH)

draw_canvas = Canvas(frame_start)
draw_canvas.pack(expand=TRUE, fill=BOTH)

features_object().create_feature(draw_canvas, 'feature A', 100, 100, 'red')
features_object().create_feature(draw_canvas, 'feature B', 300, 300, 'green')
features_object().create_feature(draw_canvas, 'feature C', 500, 500, 'magenta')


def read_id(event):
    currently_clicked = draw_canvas.find_withtag(CURRENT)
    print(f'Currently clicked instance {currently_clicked}')


draw_canvas.bind('<Button-2>', read_id)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Since all the frame is covered by the text widget, you cannot trigger those events because you cannot click on the frame.

Comment: Any workaround?